# How to go to next line while using a loop to setText in JTextArea?

Tags: jtextarea, settext

This is my code

```
 for (int m=0; m < i ; m++){
  ta1.setText( s[m].getName().toString() + ", " + s[m].getProgramName().toString() + ", "           + s[m].getUni1() + ", " + s[m].getUni2() + ", " + s[m].getUni3() + ", " );
 }
```

It's supposed to print a line from an array of student ( called s) into a `JTextArea` ( called ta1 ). the problem is that it always only prints the last student in the array.

I need to print each student in a new line. could anyone help me sort it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set text on an element, the current position in the loop will take over the last one.

Try doing this.

```
String s = "";
for(int m = 0, m <i; m++){
    s += s[m].getName.toString() + ", " + s[m].getprogramName().toString() + "\n;
}
ta1.setText(s);
```

Create a string and add each entry to it then add new line to end of each entry "\n"
Then do.

```
ta1.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setText` overwrites whatever is the current text.

You need `append` instead; you also need a "\n" at the end of a line.